# Raspberry Pi 2 Server and 2 Android devices

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi2

I am pretty new to Android development and I got a project in witch I should connect two Android Phones to each other, through a raspberry pi. Could you help me with a idea about how I should do that? I was thinking about a multithreaded java server on the raspberry and the Phones would be the clients connected to it.

Comment: raspberry pi is basically a small little computer. so try to read about server/client communications, I think [RESTfull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) should be particularly interesting to you

Comment: What type of connection you need(wired, wireless)? What purpose of connection(which data can be transfered)?

Comment: I need a wireless connection. And I want to send text messages between the two phones.